# @ModelAttribute and @SessionAttribute in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, modelattribute

As [Spring Specification said](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib), @ModelAttribute will executed before the mapping handler and @SessionAttribute will keep the model attribute in session.

Consider below scenario: form bean is created after the controller is called and is set as session attribute as well. Next time MenuController is called, createForm() will be executed again and create another new form bean. My question is: will this latest created form bean be set as session attribute? and which form bean will be bind to the parameter in method bookList()?

Hope you guys can help. Thank you.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/store")
@SessionAttribute("form")
public class MenuController {
     @ModelAttribute("form")
     public Form createForm() {
     return new Form();
     }

     @RqeustMapping("/book")
     public String bookList(@ModelAttribute("form") Form form){
     //processing the form
     }
}
```

Comment: https://www.boraji.com/spring-mvc-4-sessionattributes-example

Answer (score 5):

When the `bookList` method is invoked for the first time in a given session, then method with `@ModelAttribute('form)` is invoked, the returned value (Form object) is stored in `HttpSession` and finally the `bookList` method is invoked with the same Form object passed as an argument (obtained from session).

For the subsequent requests within the same `HttpSession`, Spring retrieves the same Form object from the session and doesn't call the method with `@ModelAttribute('form')` again till the end of the session.

After each end of the `bookList` method invocation Spring stores updated version of Form object in `HttpSession`.

If you are using Spring Boot 2.x you can debug [DefaultSessionAttributeStore#retrieveAttribute](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/DefaultSessionAttributeStore.html) method to understand this behaviour.

Comment: shouldn't `createForm()`already be called when someone visits the page `/store`, via GET?

Comment: createForm method doesn't have @RequestMapping on it, it's not an endpoint. we don't have logic for GET /store in the controller.

Comment: instead, we have GET /store/book (bookList method) and during call to GET /store/book Spring calls createForm first to pre-populate it's "Form form" argument. There are multiple ways to use \@SessionAttributes, usually you would have two endpoints GET (to prepare session attribute model) and POST (to update it). But in this particular implementation we have only GET endpoint. I think author just omitted POST implementation for brevity.

Comment: @WizardofKneup take a look at this example, it contains both implementations:
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-web-modules/spring-mvc-forms-thymeleaf/src/main/java/com/baeldung/sessionattrs/TodoControllerWithSessionAttributes.java#L21

Comment: public String bookList(@ModelAttribute("form") Form form){} can be thought as public String bookList(getFromSession("form") or createForm()){}

Answer (score 2):

The @SessionAttributes indicates that the "form" will be saved in the session. not meaning the "form" is retrieved from the session.

Comment: Actually, there are two annotations in Spring with similar names: \@SessionAttributes (used on class level) and \@SessionAttribute (used on arguments, as it has \@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)). The \@SessionAttributes defines names of session attributes in the model that should be stored in the session or some conversational storage. The \@SessionAttribute binds session attributes to arguments (Spring gets object from session and provide as an argument to method). Author of this question uses \@SessionAttribute wrongly on class level (or it must be typo).

Comment: @SessionAttributeS("form")
public class MenuController
this is correct implementation

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your mapping is generalised. It will map both to a GET method and a POST method.

> If your request mapping is a GET method,

The session attribute will hold the value of the @ModelAttribute("form") from the method createForm.

> If an attribute form is returned from a POST request,

The session Attribute will override the @Model Attribute from the createForm method.

It is helpful to remember that the @ModelAttribute will execute before the mapping handler.